# Webstorm JSON code style

Tags: json, webstorm, autoformatting

Is there a way to get an whitespace after the colon in a JSON object when autoformating in webstorm?

Actually I've got:

```
{
    key:value
}
```

What I want is

```
{
    key: value
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Intellij I go here, Webstorm might be the same...

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was a bit far to the bottom for me ;)